# Having list of tags be able to fall back to one "tags" icon when there is no space to fit all tags (with CSS only)

Tags: css, flexbox

So, here is the problem:

I have a row made with flexbox. It has 2 columns:
`|some dynamic text |      [dynamic tags]|`
Where `[dynamic tags]` can be ether a list of tags [image] 

if there is enough space or a single icon 
[image] 

when there is not enough space to fit all of them.

My current approach is to use two items making a inline line. If there is no space, one part goes to the second line, where it is hidden with `overflow: hidden`.

Here is an example: http://jsbin.com/IVUyATO/13/edit

It works pretty much fine until I want to make first and second column have equal expand factor. So they can take space equally. Like this: http://jsbin.com/IVUyATO/15/edit

But here is the problem I need to fix now - when tags go to the second row they still get space in second column and so first one doesn't use visible empty space for it's purpose.

Maybe there is completely different way of doing it, that I am missing.

Here is the html body

```
<div class="line">
  <div class="description-container">
    something 2 something 3 something 4
  </div>
  <div class="tags-container">
    <div class="more-tags">more tags</div>
    <div class="tags">
      <span>tag1</span>
      <span>tag2</span>
      <span>tag3</span>
      <span>tag4</span>
      <span>tag5</span>
      <span>tag4</span>
      <span>tag5</span>
      <span>tag6</span>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="right-container"></div>
</div>
```

```
body{
  width: 100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  background: white;
}
.line{
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  border-top:1px solid lightgray;
  border-bottom:1px solid lightgray;
}
.line > div{
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.right-container{
  width: 100px;
  background: rgba(100,0,0,0.1);
}
.line .tags-container{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: magenta;
  //TODO - Uncomment next line to see final effect
  /* overflow:hidden; */ 
  .more-tags{
    float:right;
    background: green;
    height: 50px;
    width: 80px;
  }
  .tags{
    float:right;
    background: yellow;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right:-80px;
    .tag{
      display:inline-block;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
  }
}
.line .description-container{
  background: rgba(0,0,200,0.1);
}
```

### UPDATE

I think I understood that I try to solve another problem, and I already know how to describe it. Here it is -  [Using flexbox shrink column only if it is wider than half of the container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791923/using-flexbox-shrink-column-only-if-it-is-wider-than-half-of-the-container)

Comment: Please include the code in the question

Comment: Why? You can see it in jsbin links I provide. There too much "support" code, so it will over-crowed a question I think.

Comment: See point 2 here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic